# What to do with spam-like inducing questions?

Tags: discussion

I recently came to review an answer to the following question [HeartBleed & Password Managers: Which password managers (browser or independent) were vulnerable? Do I need to change passwords? When?](https://superuser.com/q/739593/228536) and instantly struck the Spam flag, as looking at it without any sort of reference, it was phrased in a similar way as most product spam we come across here.

However, there's a problem: the OP asks about which products are indeed compromised. The current answers deal exclusively on reporting that Product X wasn't compromised. Although I don't like the question in its current form, it seems that those kinds of answers either fall on one of two hypothesis, either it was or it wasn't compromised.

But here lie the problems: few if none companies will innocently divulge their vulnerability at any given time (it would not serve them any practical purpose, and at the worst case it would scare its users), and those that weren't vulnerable are, for the time being, creating spam-like answers.

Any answers to the question may refer to a password manager and although the current answers do answer (in the form of "It wasn't vulnerable"), they seem more like spam than anything else.

I would like to get the community's opinion on this matter.

Comment: I'm not convinced that's a question that needs to remain open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a question [without an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Spam being a secondary concern.